# How install Tizen.NET NuGet package in TIzen IDE?

Tags: c++, c, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I'm trying to develop a simple app on Tizen that uses the accelerometer.

https://developer.samsung.com/tizen/blog/en-us/2019/04/15/how-to-use-sensors-on-a-galaxy-watch

states:

> To use sensor features on Galaxy Watch and other wearable
> applications, refer to the Tizen.NET NuGet package. The
> Tizen.Wearable.CircularUI provides the Xamarin.Forms extension
> controls, which are used for wearables.

Clicking the link "Tizen.NET NuGet package" navigates to:

https://developer.samsung.com/tizen/About-Tizen.NET/Tizen.NET.html

But it doesn't contain instructions on how to install ?

I'm just learning how to use Tizen and C and not sure how to install the package. Should the "Tizen.NET NuGet package" in the Tizen package manager be available at https://developer.samsung.com/tizen/About-Tizen.NET/Tizen.NET.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply,

- Tizen Studio => C/C++ application, Web application
- Visual Studio + Tizen Plugin + Base-SDK (included in Tizen Studio) => C# application

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged c and c++ however all linked materials use .NET and c#.

It looks like you want to use .NET so you'll need Visual Studio with [Tizen plugin](https://docs.tizen.org/application/vstools/install) installed.
Then you should [create .Net project from template](https://docs.tizen.org/application/dotnet/get-started/wearable/first-app/). It will have Tizen.NET NuGet installed and you'll be able to follow sensors tutorial.

If instead you really wanted to use c you'll need Tizen Studio and follow [this tutorial](https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/tutorials/feature/app-sensor-accelerator/).